# Django, Redirect user to different page by user's type

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to redirect user to different page by user's type when they login.

I'm using django-allauth for login system and I created a profile table for user that has a OnetoOne field with the user table, like this....

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('sup', 'supplier'),
    ('dis', 'distributor'),
)
type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
nationality = CountryField()
company = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
skype = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

After their login, they will access a view called "redirect". (exampale.com/app/rediect)

for this view, I'm using this

```
#views.py
@login_required
def redirect(request):
if request.user.profile.filter(type='sup'):
    return redirect('/app/a')
elif request.user.profile.filter(type='dis'):
    return redirect('app/b')
```

However, when I access this page. There is a error

```
File "/opt/project/app/views.py", line 27, in redirect
if request.user.profile.filter(type='adv'):
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need filter to access onetoone field. `user.profile` already return profile instance, so you can acces profile type direcly:

```
if request.user.profile.type == "sup":
    return redirect('/app/a')
if request.user.profile.type == "dis":
    return redirect('/app/b')
```

Also you need to rename your view to not override Django's `redirect` function:

```
@login_required
def my_redirect(request):
...
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I just tried your solution. but there is a new error.
  File "/opt/project/app/views.py", line 27, in redirect
    if request.user.profile.type == "sup":
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @user3114168 see updated answer. Your view name clashed with django builtin `redirect` function, so you need to rename your view.

Comment: Traceback:

File "/opt/django/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/opt/django/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

Comment: File "/opt/django/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/project/panel/views.py" in redirect
  28.         return redirect('/app/a')

File "/opt/project/panel/views.py" in redirect
  27.     if request.user.profile.type == "sup":

Exception Type: AttributeError at /panel/redirect/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @user3114168 yep, just rename your view.

Comment: Yes!! it works after renamed the view name. 
fixed is for a few hrs before....
Thank you very much for you help!!